# php array_filter is filtering too much

Tags: php, array-filter

Here is the code :

```
<?php 
$a_campagnes = $this->campagne->get_campagnes_client();
foreach($a_campagnes as $o_camp){
    if($o_camp->groupes){
        foreach($o_camp->groupes as $o_groupe){
            if($o_groupe->IDGroupe == $this->session->o_user->IDGroupe){ echo 'ok';}
        }
    }
}
$a_campagnes = array_filter($a_campagnes, function($o_camp){
    if($o_camp->groupes){
        foreach($o_camp->groupes as $o_groupe){
            if($o_groupe->IDGroupe == $this->session->o_user->IDGroupe) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

`$a_campagnes` contains at first 10 objects

The result of the first foreach is `okokokok`

The result of `$a_campagnes` after the `array_filter` (which is the same code as the first foreach) is `null`

Where are the four objects matching my first foreach?

### EDIT

Just tried that piece of code:

```
$i_id_groupe_user = $this->session->o_user->IDGroupe;
        foreach($a_campagnes as $o_camp){
            if($o_camp->groupes){
                foreach($o_camp->groupes as $o_groupe){
                    if($o_groupe->IDGroupe == $i_id_groupe_user){ echo 'ok';}
                }
            }
        }
        $a_campagnes = array_filter($a_campagnes, function($o_camp) use ($i_id_groupe_user){
            if($o_camp->groupes){
                foreach($o_camp->groupes as $o_groupe){
                    if($o_groupe->IDGroupe == $i_id_groupe_user) return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
```

It gives the same result as before

Comment: Please make sure that you are getting $o_camp->groupes  in your if condition. If yes then Please check foreach.

Comment: Condition is good, `$o_camp->groupes` is an object of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this` doesn't exist inside anonymous functions, and you're trying to use it as if it was inside your class scope, which would be even less logical.

If you want to use whatever `$this->session` is inside your `array_filter()` callback, you'll have to either declare a class method specifically for that, or tell the anonymous function that it can use it, like this:

```
$session = $this->session;
$a_campagnes = array_filter($a_campagnes, function($o_camp) use ($session) {
    if ($o_camp->groupes) {
        foreach($o_camp->groupes as $o_groupe) {
            if ($o_groupe->IDGroupe == $session->o_user->IDGroupe) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Just thought about that. Unfortunately, it does not change anything (see my edit)

Comment: Well, that's what was wrong with your initial code ... Anything else would be a flaw in your program's logic, which only you know and therefore only you could debug. Also, you would've seen this if you had error_reporting, display_errors enabled ...

Comment: Well, you are right... Just found the problem... my variable `$a_campagnes`was an object of objects... array_filter only accepts arrays as input. Sometime, it's usefull to look at error logs indeed...